Auto-update calculated column values
I want to add an additional column (Open Time) in my table which calculates the difference between latest DOOR OPEN and DOOR CLOSE. And is triggered by the message DOOR CLOSE. And I want this column to calculate the difference in time every time new rows are added to the column without me having to run the query again:



Date
TriggerTime
EventMessageheader
Open_Time




07/10/2024
3:31:00
Task 1
NULL


07/10/2024
3:42:53
DOOR OPEN
NULL


07/10/2024
3:43:53
Task 2
NULL


07/10/2024
3:57:00
DOOR CLOSE
0:14:07


07/10/2024
3:58:00
Task 3
NULL


07/10/2024
4:10:00
Task 4
NULL


07/10/2024
4:13:00
Task 5
NULL


07/10/2024
4:20:22
DOOR OPEN
NULL


07/10/2024
4:21:00
Task 7
NULL


07/10/2024
4:24:14
Task 8
NULL


07/10/2024
4:27:00
Task 9
NULL


07/10/2024
4:28:00
Task 10
NULL


07/10/2024
4:43:00
DOOR CLOSE
0:22:38



SQL code:
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Events;

CREATE TABLE #Events
(
    Date date,
    TriggerTime time(0) NOT NULL,
    EventMessage varchar(50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT #Events (Date,TriggerTime, EventMessage)
VALUES ('07/10/2024', '3:31:00', 'Task 1'),
       ('07/10/2024', '3:42:53', 'DOOR OPEN'),
       ('07/10/2024', '3:43:53', 'Task 2'),
       ('07/10/2024', '3:57:00', 'DOOR CLOSE'),
       ('07/10/2024', '3:58:00', 'Task 3'),
       ('07/10/2024', '4:10:00', 'Task 4'),
       ('07/10/2024', '4:13:00', 'Task 5'),
       ('07/10/2024', '4:20:22', 'DOOR OPEN'),
       ('07/10/2024', '4:21:00', 'Task 7'),
       ('07/10/2024', '4:24:14', 'Task 8'),
       ('07/10/2024', '4:27:00', 'Task 9'),
       ('07/10/2024', '4:28:00', 'Task 10'),
       ('07/10/2024', '4:43:00', 'DOOR CLOSE');

I tried using the following query, it works for calculating the column but I have rerun it to get updated values in open time column
ALTER TABLE #Events ADD Open_Time TIME(0);

-- Update this column with query value
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        *,
        SUM(CASE WHEN EventMessage LIKE 'DOOR%'THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)OVER(ORDER BY TriggerTime) AS Mark
    FROM 
        #Events
)
UPDATE C1
SET C1.Open_Time = CAST((CAST(C1.TriggerTime AS datetime)-CAST(C2.TriggerTime AS datetime)) AS time(0))  
FROM CTE C1 
LEFT JOIN CTE C2 ON C1.EventMessage = 'DOOR CLOSE' 
                 AND C2.EventMessage = 'DOOR OPEN' 
                 AND C2.Mark + 1 = C1.Mark


You could use an insert trigger to calculate the Open Time

Or create a view.

As I stated in the SG, smells like an XY Problem; this should be a VIEW.

@Thom A, I want the base table to get updated as I am using the values of this database elsewhere. So viewing/querying to get that data on the fly won't help.

Then update your queries to use the VIEW when you need this information. This type of information isn't something to store on the table. This logic is easily achievable with LAST_VALUE.

why do you think a view won't help ? Just use the view to read the values elsewhere too, you can query a view the same way you can query a table

You can even update many views

As I mention in the comments, don't store this in the table, instead calculate it using a VIEW. Then you can query the said VIEW instead and it'll always have the correct value.
The VIEW would look something like:
CREATE VIEW dbo.ViewName AS
    SELECT Date,
           TriggerTime,
           EventMessage,
           LAST_VALUE(CASE EventMessage WHEN 'DOOR OPEN' THEN TriggerTime END) IGNORE NULLS OVER (ORDER BY TriggerTime) AS OpenTime
    FROM dbo.YourTable;

If you aren't on 2022+ then you can use MAX, but you'll have to "jump through the hoop" of getting your separate date and time values into a single datetime value, and then you can CONVERT it back to a time:
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW dbo.ViewName AS
    SELECT Date,
           TriggerTime,
           EventMessage,
           CONVERT(time(0),MAX(CASE EventMessage WHEN 'DOOR OPEN' THEN CONVERT(datetime2(0),CONVERT(varchar(10),Date,112) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(10),TriggerTime,114)) END) OVER (ORDER BY TriggerTime)) AS OpenTime
    FROM dbo.YourTable;
GO


Thanks @Thom A., I had doubts about whether a 'VIEW' can be imported to Power BI as a Direct query, It can actually. This solves my problem. Thanks again.
